# C++ Filehandling: Difference between ios::app and ios::ate?

Tags: c++, file, fstream, std

What's the difference between `ios::ate` and `ios:app` when writing to a file.
In my view, `ios::app` gives you the ability to move around in the file, whereas with `ios::ate` it can only read/write at the end of the file. Is this correct?

Comment: By the way, it is really `ios_base::ate` and `ios_base::app`.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

It’s the other way around. When `ios::ate` is set, the initial position will be the end of the file, but you are free to seek thereafter. When `ios::app` is set, *all* output operations are performed at the end of the file. Since all writes are implicitly preceded by seeks, there is no way to write elsewhere.

Answer (score 48):

They are specified as follows (in 27.5.3.1.4 of C++11):

> `app` seek to end before each write
>
> `ate` open and seek to end immediately after opening

With `ios::app` the write position in the file is "sticky" -- all writes are at the end, no matter where you seek.

Answer (score 37):

It is very well documented [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/fstream/open/).

`ios::ate` "sets the stream's position indicator to the end of the stream on opening."

`ios::app` "set the stream's position indicator to the end of the stream before each output operation."

This means the difference is that `ios::ate` puts your position to the end of the file when you open it. `ios::app` instead puts it at the end of the file every time you flush your stream. If, for example, you have two programs that write to the same log file, `ios::ate` will override anything that was added to the file by the other program since your program opened it. `ios:app` will instead jump to the end of file each time your program adds a log entry.

Comment: The link doesn't work. The documentation is available here: https://cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/open/

Answer (score 12):

`ios::app`--> "We cannot move the pointer. It will be only at end."

`ios::ate`--> "We can move the record pointer to any other place."

Answer (score 3):

I'm adding an answer here because I recently ran into a situation where ios::ate should have worked, but most online documentation on this topic, like [this](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/fstream/open/) page on cplusplus.com, and similar answers on this post turned out to be only partially correct or at least misleading.

What everyone is correct about is that ios::app will open a file without deleting its contents, and move the cursor to the end of the file before EVERY write to the file. So using a function like seekp is more or less useless when a file has been opened with ios::app, because the cursor will move automatically to the end of the file with every write, before the writing occurs.

What else everyone is correct about is that ios::ate will not move the cursor to the end of the file before every write. So functions like seekp will work with ios::ate. Also technically correct is that ios::ate will move the cursor to the end of the file when you open it, but that is a technicality -- see next paragraph.

What does NOT line up with most documentation and forum answers is that in reality (please someone comment if they have a reasonable explanation for my experience here) opening a file with ios::ate will delete its contents, much like ios::trunc. Which leaves you with not a lot of great options if you want to open a non-empty file for writing, not delete its contents, and retain the ability to effectively move your stream position, as with seekp.

The only way I found to solve my problem was to use a solution I found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47014463/ofstream-open-modes-ate-vs-app) Stack Overflow post, namely to open the file with flags (ios::in | ios::ate), even though I'm opening an ofstream for writing. This makes me somewhat uncomfortable to do but it's what I'm doing for now.

Comment: I should have mentioned that a shortcoming of opening file with ios::in | ios::ate won't work if the file doesn't already exist.

Answer (score 1):

The `ios::ate` option is for input and output operations and
`ios::app` allows us to add data to the end of file.

Comment: Can you provide a link to documentation?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, and it'll help you understand (clear the old data first - I personally combine `ios::in` and `ios::ate`):

```
ofstream myFile("test.txt", ios::ate|ios::in);
myFile << "Hello World";
myFile.seekp(6, ios::beg);
myFile << "Hello World";
myFile.close();
```

Test with `ios::app`, it has some differences.