# Why does tellp() return 0 for ios::app but not for ios::ate?

Tags: c++, file-handling

I have the following code snippet :

```
ofile.open("New1.dat",ios::app|ios::binary|ios::ate);
long bytes = ofile.tellp()/sizeof(t);
cout<<ofile.tellp()<<endl;    //line 1
t.input(bytes);
ofile.write((char *)&t,sizeof(t));
ofile.close();
```

When I remove `ios::app` or `ios::ate`, the output of `line 1` is 0, howeever only when both of them are together, they give the correct file location. Why does this happen?
P.S. I know the difference between ios::app and ios::ate.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The answer is likely hidden somewhere here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [std::ios::openmode](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode) (Section 27.5.3.1.4 of C++11)

`std::ios::app` means to seek to the end of stream before each write. So stream may be not be at end **before** any write operation. No matter where the pointer is (`0` or somewhere else) writing is always done at end. (Implicit seek to end before each write operation)

on the other hand `std::ios::ate` means to seek to the end of stream immediately after open and thus is guaranteed to return the size of file.

Further reading: [C++ Filehandling: Difference between ios:app and ios:ate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10359702/c-filehandling-difference-between-iosapp-and-iosate)