# ofstream open modes: ate vs app

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, fstream

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10359702/c-filehandling-difference-between-iosapp-and-iosate) question asks the difference between `app` and `ate` and both the answers and [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/basic_ofstream) imply that the only difference is that `app` means that the write cursor is put at the end of the file before each write operation, whereas `ate` means that the write cursor is put at the end of the file only when opening.

What I'm actually seeing (in VS 2012) is that specifying `ate` *discards the contents of an existing file*, whereas `app` does not (it appends new content to the previously existing content). In other words, `ate` seems to imply `trunc`.

The following statement appends "Hello" to an existing file:

```
ofstream("trace.log", ios_base::out|ios_base::app) << "Hello\n";
```

But the following statement replaces the contents of the file with just "Hello":

```
ofstream("trace.log", ios_base::out|ios_base::ate) << "Hello\n";
```

The MSDN documentation for VS 6.0 implies that shouldn't happen (but this sentence seems to have been withdrawn in later versions of Visual Studio):

> **ios::trunc**:   If the file already exists, its contents are discarded.
>   This mode is implied if ios::out is specified, and ios::ate, ios::app,
>   and ios:in are not specified.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to combine `std::ios::in` with `std::ios::ate` then seek the end of the file and append the text:

Consider I have a file "data.txt" which contains this line:

```
"Hello there how are you today? Ok fine thanx. you?"
```

Now I open it:

1: std::ios::app:

```
std::ofstream out("data.txt", std::ios::app);

out.seekp(10); // I want to move the write pointer to position 10

out << "This line will be appended to the end of the file";

out.close();
```

The result is not what I wanted: No moving the write pointer but only the text is always appended to the end.

2: std::ios::ate:

```
std::ofstream out2("data.txt", std::ios::ate);

out2 << "This line will be ate to the end of the file";

out2.close();
```

The result above is not what I wanted no text appended but the content is truncated!

To solve it combine `ate` with `in`:

```
std::ofstream out2("data.txt", std::ios::ate | std::ios::in);

out2 << "This line will be ate to the end of the file";

out2.close();
```

Now the text is appended to the end but what is the difference:

As I said app doesn't allow moving the write pointer but ate does.

```
std::ofstream out2("data.txt", std::ios::ate | std::ios::in);

out2.seekp(5, std::ios::end); // add the content after the end with 5 positions.

out2 << "This line will be ate to the end of the file";

out2.close();
```

Above we can move the write pointer to the position we want while with app we cannot.

- Look at this example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6cDcTp1gn4Q

Comment: Yes. But as you can see combining read flags `std::ios::in` with write flags for a write stream is such a stupid logic in fstream.