# Writing to ofstream using ios::ate overwrites existing file

Tags: c++, ofstream

I am trying to append a sequence of matrices to disk as CSV and have found that using ios::ate overwrites any existing file created previously. To illustrate this problem via a simplified model, a second call to the function write_nums() below results in the loss of anydata written in the first call. Is there a way to fix this?

The solution to this question previously given in [ofstream open modes: ate vs app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47014463/ofstream-open-modes-ate-vs-app) does not seem optimal as it only works provided the file to which the output is directed already exists.

```
void write_nums()
{
    std::ofstream out_file;

    out_file.open("test.txt", std::ofstream::ate);
    if (!out_file.good())
    {
        std::cerr << "Error while opening output file!" << '\n';
    }
    out_file.seekp(0, std::ios::end);
    out_file << "{";
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        out_file << i << ',';
    }
    out_file.seekp(-1, std::ios::end);
    out_file << "}";
}
```

Comment: "it only works provided the file to which the output is directed already exists", no, with `app` flag the file will be created if it does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

That happens because `ios_base::ate` is an *additional* flag, the "primary" flags that determine the open mode are `in`, `out` and `app`.

Valid open mode flag combinations are listed in [[input.output]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/input.output#tab:iostreams.file.open.modes).

Since you specified none of `in`, `out` or `app`, `ofstream::open` defaults to mode `out`, which is equivalent of `"w"`, which truncates the file.

`ios_base::ate` is useful in combination with `ios_base::in` for "tailing" a file.

For appending to a file there is `ios_base::app` which matches your situation exactly.

Comment: Doesn't `std::ofstream` always default to `std::ios::out` and `std::ifstream` to `std::ios::in`?

Answer (score 2):

`std::ofstream::ate` truncates the existing file. One of the [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47015066/11455105) for the question you have linked also mentions it, you have to combine `ate` with `in` to avoid truncation. Using `app` won't let you play with the seek.

```
void write_nums()
{
    std::ofstream out_file("test.txt", std::ofstream::ate | std::ofstream::in);
    if (!out_file.good())
    {
        std::cerr << "Error while opening output file!" << '\n';
    }
    out_file.seekp(0, std::ios::end);
    out_file << "{";
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        out_file << i << ',';
    }
    out_file.seekp(-1, std::ios::end);
    out_file << "}";
}
```